# Use robocopy to mirror source but ignore timestamp

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

I want to backup a folder to a share on a linux nas with robocopy.

I use the commandline `robocopy /mir <source> <dest>`

After a succesfull copy in explorer the timestamps are equal but somehow robocopy copies the same file the next time it runs and claims source file is newer. Seems to be a problem with the smb version on the nas.

Now I can use `/xn` switch to prevent the file copy but that will also prevent the file from being copied the next time I run the same job.

So my question is: How do I use robocopy to ignore the timestamp but only copy a file if the file size changed (I know this would not be a 100% solution) but since I want to backup office documents and pictures, this would be OK for me.

Comment: You already know this idea has issues - content can change without affecting file size. Also, the modified date can be altered by things like AV. I wrote a back up program (to back up my Windows files to my Linux NAS too) because I ran into these problems using `XCOPY` and `Robocopy`. You are better to get the HASH of the file and then compare them but this isn't do-able in robocopy. Since robocopy isn't the right tool (IMO), why not use other software? What actually is the issue? If you're only copying office documents and pictures, I assume the time it takes isn't really a problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> After a succesfull copy in explorer the timestamps are equal but
>   somehow Robocopy copies the same file the next time it runs and claims
>   source file is newer. Seems to be a problem with the smb version on
>   the nas.

Add the `/FFT` switch with Robocopy:

```
ROBOCOPY /MIR /FFT <source> <dest>
```

[**Robocopy Switch**](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

```
/FFT : Assume FAT File Times (2-second date/time granularity).
```

[<sub>**Better Description**</sub>](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx)

> /FFT uses fat file timing instead of NTFS. This means the granularity is a    > bit less precise. For across-network share operations
>   this seems to be much more reliable - just don't rely on the file
>   timings to be completely precise to the second.

Comment: That did the trick. Thumbs up